# log4j and DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch() function

Tags: java, log4j

I would like to override log4j configuration at runtime with DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch() function. It's work when the string name of file parameter is hard-coded. For example : `DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch("C:/some/path/log4j.xml");`

But my log4j.xml is in EAR file (in a JAR in the lib directory) and how can I access it at runtime ?

I tested `DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch("log4j.xml");` but it seems that Glassfish is trying to search file from `${GLASSFISH_HOME}/glassfish/domains/domain1/config` where is located my old log4j.xml file to override...so actually my code load, reset and reload configuration from the same file...

I'm just looking for a way to load my log4j.xml inside my EAR

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke [`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.xml")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) on a class in your JAR/EAR to read the `log4j.xml` file located at the root of the JAR/EAR. Then, pass the resulting `InputStream` to [`DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(InputStream, LoggerRepository)`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.io.InputStream,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29)

Alternatively, you can invoke `DOMConfigurator`.[`configure`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html#configure%28java.net.URL%29)`(getClass()`.[`getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)`("/log4j.xml"))`, where `getClass()` returns a `Class` object in your JAR/EAR.

Comment: Thanks. Statics methods of DOMConfigurator do not contains methods with InputStream parameter whereas non static methods do. Problem solved !

Comment: If you want to stick to static methods, you can use my second proposal, which gets the `URL` of the XML file and passes it to a static method of `DOMConfigurator`.